# Passing value to controller of a directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the definition of my directive

```
module.exports = ()=>{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/components/appointment/appointment.html",
    scope: {iter: '=iter'},
    controller: "appointmentCtrl"
  };
};
```

And i am calling it using

```
appointment(iter="itenary")
```

Now the problem is when i try to render it in template using

```
p(ng-bind="iter.itenery")
```

It works fine and shows me the proper string that it is supported to but inside the controller which is

```
module.exports = function($scope,$rootScope,api){
  console.log($scope.iter.itenery);

  $scope.event = function(){
    console.log($scope.iter.itenery);
  }
});
```

It returns undefined. Now in order to debug, i added `$scope.event` function to a button in template that is triggered on button click. At that time i get the correct value that i expected.

This leads me to believe that the controller is being called before the value of `$scope.iter` is being set. Now i need to value in controller to render template data `onLoad`. How can i do that ?

### Edit

The code for template is

```
.appointment(ng-init="")
  p(ng-bind="iter.itenery")
  ul.dayTitle
    li(ng-repeat="day in [] | range: totDays")
      h5(data-ng-class="{'active': day==currentDay}" ng-click="setDay(day)") Day {{day}}
    li
      h5.add(ng-click="addDay()") +
  .day
    .hour(ng-repeat="i in curIter")
      .label(ng-show="i.index>10") {{i.index-1}}00 - {{i.index}}00
      .label(ng-show="i.index<10") 0{{i.index-1}}00 - 0{{i.index}}00
      .label(ng-show="i.index==10") 0{{i.index-1}}00 - {{i.index}}00
      .half.first(dropzone data-time-slot="{{(i.index*2-1)}}")
        img(draggable src="{{i.first.icon}}" id="{{i.first._id}}")
      .half.second(dropzone data-time-slot="{{(i.index*2)}}")
        img(draggable src="{{i.second.icon}}" id="{{i.second._id}}")
```

Note the second line binding is working properly but not in controller

Comment: Can you provide the generate HTML?

Comment: @kopranb do you mean the template ?

Comment: no, the HTML generated by your template engine.

Comment: @kopranb The html is minified, i have attached the complete jade file

Comment: @kopranb in case you still need html, i have added it here http://pastebin.com/284HksyJ

Comment: The [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service might work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137483/discussion-between-georoot-and-kopranb).